# Why does sed ignore the file variable?

Tags: bash, variables, sed

If I place the file path name directly into the code, it runs as expected - replacing the code within the file between those two START-/ENDTAGs.  But, if I use a variable instead of that file path name, it will either delete the entire section to be replaced or ignore it completely.

```
#!/bin/bash

CF_HTMLHEAD=$(cat ./cf_templates/cf_HtmlHead.txt)
...
sed '
    '"$ENDTAG"' r $CF_HTMLHEAD
    '"$STARTTAG"','"$ENDTAG"' d
' -i $TARGETDIR
```

I've tried using `'"$CF_HTMLHEAD"'  ,  '$CF_HTMLHEAD'  and "$CF_HTMLHEAD"` 
and changing the variable definition, itself: `CF_HTMLHEAD='$(...)'  ,  ="$(...)"`  , and all combinations between the two lines that I could think of.

Any clues as to how sed can read a file input variable??

Comment: IMO using `'"$CF_HTMLHEAD"'` should fix it.

Comment: Dropping out of single quotes should make the variable work correctly. That said doesn't `r` expect a filename and not literal contents?

Comment: Wait.. Is `./cf_templates/cf_HtmlHead.txt` the file you want to insert, or does it contain the path to the file you want to insert? If it's the former, you should do `CF_HTMLHEAD=./cf_templates/cf_HtmlHead.txt`

Comment: Hey, hey!  That worked!  (Sorry, that was my mistake.  I meant file name, as you were able to gather.)  Thank you both very much.  I was going nuts over those single and double quotes...

Comment: If you have a solution that worked you should add it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: BTW, the quoting here is really silly. Why constantly switch back and forth between single- and double-quoted contexts instead of just staying in a double-quoted context the whole way through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Muru's and Etan Reisner's insight, the issue was in the variable declaration.

```
CF_HTMLHEAD=./cf_templates/cf_HtmlHead.txt
```

Once I took off the ' and ", the code ran for me.  Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Just using double quotes is a lot tidier:

```
sed "
    /$ENDTAG/ r $CF_HTMLHEAD
    /$STARTTAG/,/$ENDTAG/ d
" -i "$TARGETDIR"
```

I'm assuming you didn't put the slashes in your *TAG variables