# Is there a way to loop variables from another file into my bash script?

Tags: bash

Sorry to be a pain, but I'm not sure how I can loop values from an outside file, into my bash script as variables.  I have three variable names in my bash script:

```
$TAGBEGIN
$TAGEND
$MYCODE
```

In a separate varSrc.txt file, I have several variables:

```
@ a - Some marker
tagBegin_a='/<!-- Begin A -->/'
tagEnd_a='/<!-- End A -->/'
code_a=' [ some code to replace in between tags ] '

@ b - Some marker
tagBegin_b='/<!-- Begin B -->/'
tagEnd_b='/<!-- End B -->/'
code_b=' [ some code to replace in between tags ] '

@ c - Some marker
...
```

I need my bash script to be able to loop through each "@ marker"* section and perform a function:

```
source varSrc.txt

$TAGBEGIN
$TAGEND
$MYCODE
...
sed '           
    '"$TAGEND"' R '"$MYCODE"'
    '"$TAGBEGIN"','"$TAGEND"' d
' -i $TARGETDIR
```

Note: sed code logic (not quoting mess) courtesy of Glenn J.

I need some kind of looping logic like:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= markers in varSrc.txt ; i++) {
// set bash vars equal to varSrc values
$TAGBEGIN=  $tagBegin_i 
$TAGEND= $tagEnd_i
$MYCODE= $code_i

// run the 'sed' replace command
    sed '           
        '"$TAGEND"' R '"$MYCODE"'
        '"$TAGBEGIN"','"$TAGEND"' d
    ' -i $TARGETDIR

}
```

Is this something that can be feasibly done in a bash script and is this a good approach? Any suggestions, pointers or guidance is very, very appreciated!

*(which I don't think is a real marker I can use)

Comment: Your other file, notably, is **not** in bash syntax. Bash variable assignments are `foo=bar`, not `$foo=bar` or `$foo =bar`.

Comment: Oops, I'll fix that.  (Sorry, too many variables floating around in my head...)

Comment: Also, `@` isn't valid comment syntax usable for a marker.

Comment: ...if these items are "something to fix", then my entire answer was predicated on an assumption (that you needed to parse non-bash syntax) that may not be true. Please be more careful when asking questions in the future.

Comment: Also -- is there a reason you want this particular input file format, rather than letting us suggest one for you? The choice of formats has a significant impact on the choice of algorithms &c.

Comment: Also, if you're trying to edit HTML or XML this way, the entire approach is wrongheaded, and you should be using a format-aware template language such as Genshi rather than hacking around with `sed`.

Comment: (...or mustache, if you want a template language that can be invoked directly by command-line tools and are willing to give up guarantees as to output format validity; I don't recommend giving up those guarantees unless you're sure of what they mean security-wise -- ensuring that data stays data rather than becoming code can save the people loading the pages you're generating from a wide variety of injection attacks).

Comment: Also, all-caps variable names are reserved for use by your shell (such as `PWD` or `PS1`) or your system environment (like `LD_PRELOAD`, `LANG`, `LC_ALL`, etc); you shouldn't make up new all-caps names in your scripts. This is POSIX-specified convention for environment variable names, and shell variables use the name namespace. See fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html

Comment: Oh, wow!  Your explanations are amazing.  Sorry about that.  (I'm trying to get the hang of bash scripting after I inherited a script from someone else.  (I'm the new intern.))  Right now, I'm just testing the varSrc.txt since eventually the (e.g.) "code_a" will be code that will replace the html with Coldfusion - but I can't get my hands on the Coldfusion code until my tests work...I'll also be sure to look into Genshi and how security plays into this particular script.  
I'll be testing your suggestions and see what we get.  Thank you for imparting your "bashing" knowledge!  :)

Comment: (oops -- "use the name namespace" should have been "use the same namespace". And I'm glad that my feedback here is helpful!)

Comment: Don't blame me for that quoting hell. I suggested [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33685045/7552)

Comment: I edited the question to address Glenn Jackman's last comment. (I just didn't want to take credit where it wasn't due and didn't think about the "quoting hell" I made when testing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Answering the question as amended]*

There's no need use use, iterate over, or think about markers at all. Leave them out.

```
source varSrc.txt
for beginVar in "${!tagBegin_@}"; do  # Iterate over defined begin variable names
  endVar=tagEnd_${var#tagBegin_}      # Generate the name of the end variable
  codeVar=code_${var#tagBegin_}       # Generate the name of the code variable
  begin=${!beginVar}                  # Look up the contents of the begin variable
  end=${!endVar}                      # Look up the contents of the end variable
  code=${!codeVar}                    # Look up the contents of the code variable

  sed -e "$end R $code" -e "$begin,$end d" -i "$file"
done
```

Comment: When I ran this, I got a "sed: "-e expression #2, char 55: unexpected `,' " error message.  Is my varSrv.txt  `code_a` variable messing something up?  I just put a string value in there for testing (e.g. code_a="This is a test A.").

Comment: @arl, ...in general, I'm telling you how to loop over variables in bash; I'm not telling you anything about `sed`.

Comment: Woah, you're fast.  I put the '/<!-- ... -->/' in my declarations, too.  I'm just trying to narrow the issue down.  I'll research sed some more (and those darn single vs double quotes).   Thank you, Charles Duffy!

Comment: err. `bash -x yourscript`, that is; will do a great deal of good to make it clear where the issue is, in any event.

Comment: @arl, the important thing to keep in mind about quotes, btw, is that syntactic quotes are strictly for the shell's use. `sed` has no way of telling whether you used single or double quotes in any given place; it's simply a matter of telling the shell how to behave when parsing and running expansions.

Answer (score 2):

*[Answers original, pre-amended question]*

`source` only works if your input file is valid bash syntax; it isn't. Thus, you'll need to parse it yourself, something like the following:

```
begin= end= code=
while IFS= read -r; do
  case $REPLY in
    @*)
      # we saw a marker; process all vars seen so far
      [[ $begin && $end && $code ]] || continue # do nothing if we have no vars seen
      sed -e "$end R $code" -e "$begin,$end d" -i "$file"
      ;;
    '$TAGBEGIN='*) begin=${REPLY#'$TAGBEGIN='} ;;
    '$TAGEND='*)   end=${REPLY#'$TAGEND='} ;;
    '$MYCODE='*)   code=${REPLY#'$MYCODE='} ;;
  esac
done <varSrc.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is export your variables in your second file an the execute the script within your current environment (with a dot before the script) to get the variable names/markers you can parse the file and search for an $ or @

Comment: There's no need to parse the file **if** the input is modified to be able to be sourced -- bash incorporates tools for for searching through the list of defined variables for variable names with a known prefix.

Comment: Also, if it's sourced in, there's no need to export anything; the variables can be accessed as native shell variables without needing to be copied to the environment.

Comment: ...so, I'd just ask the shell to list variables starting with `tagBegin_`, and assume that `tagEnd_` and `tagCode_` variables with similar suffixes will also exist.